# I want to get every command that has 3 letters and only three letters

Tags: bash, regex, awk

I don't get the output I expect using `apropos -k .  |awk '/^.../ {print $1}'` am I completely overthinking this? In this sample output only zsh should have come back.
I also tried this

```
apropos -k . | awk '/^\w{3}$/ {print $1}'
```

Here's a small sample

```
zmq_version
zmq_vmci
zmq_z85_decode
zmq_z85_encode
znew
zpool
zram-generator
zram-generator.conf
zramctl
zsh
zshall
zshbuiltins
zshcalsys
zshcompctl
zshcompsys
zshcompwid
zshcontrib
zshexpn
zshmisc
zshmodules
```

Answer (score 2):

Your 1st regex only checks whether there are *at least* three characters – it doesn't check what comes *after* them (i.e. the characters can be followed by a 4th letter just as well as they can be followed by a space), and it is not bounded with `$` so it'll happily match just the start of the input, without requiring that it match the whole input.

Your 2nd regex does all of that correctly, but (like the 1st one) it still applies to the *entire line* – which of course has other text, such as the command description.

For a whole-line regex (your 1st attempt) you would need to check the 4th character as well and require a space to be there, instead of a 4th letter or anything else:

```
/^\w{3} / {print $1}
```

Alternatively (for your 2nd attempt), match the 1st field instead of the whole line (awk automatically splits each line into whitespace-separated fields by default, unless changed via `-F`) and require that the regex match the whole field, not just the beginning:

```
$1 ~ /^...$/ {print $1}
```

```
$1 ~ /^.{3}$/ {print $1}
```

Alternatively #2, now that you're working with individual fields, you can also directly check the length of the value without a regex:

```
length($1) == 3 {print $1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```shell
ls /usr/bin/ | awk '{if (length($1) == 3) print $1}'
```